# Why my mac lldb generate core file not recognized by lldb itself?

Tags: macos, file, load, lldb, coredump

```
$cat testleak01.cpp
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int*p=new int[3];
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with debug information

```
$g++ testleak01.cpp -g
```

And then start it with lldb

```
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 22 at testleak01.cpp:4, address = 0x0000000100000f86
(lldb) r
Process 87960 launched: '/Users/x/Documents/learn/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 87960 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x60b7ec, 0x0000000100000f86 a.out`main + 22 at testleak01.cpp:4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f86 a.out`main + 22 at testleak01.cpp:4
   1    #include<iostream>
   2    int main()
   3    {
-> 4        int*p=new int[3];
   5        return 0;
   6    }
(lldb) process save-core mycore
... a lot of stuff
```

Then after half a minute I got a huge core file(500M+) like this with root as its owner

```
-rw-------   1 root  staff  589529088  2 25 21:06 mycore
```

Then I tried to load it and

```
$lldb -c mycore
(lldb) target create --core "mycore"
error: Unable to find process plug-in for core file '/Users/x/Documents/learn/mycore'
```

Why it doesn't recognize the core file generate by itself?
I was expecting to use lldb to load both a.out and mycore to check the dumped file as process image.

Comment: We're you running lldb as root when you created the core file? If not, why was it created as root? I'm wondering if that error message isn't a red-herring, and the problem is actually a permissions issue. Try chown-ing it to your user.

Comment: Good suggestion.  lldb's error messaging for a core file it can't read is poor, I need to fix that.  This could be "File not readable".

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a wrongly generated core file. Multiple parallel instances of the same app crashed nearly at the same time and I got 3 core files. For 2 of them lldb worked fine, but for one of them I got "Unable to find process plug-in for core file".

```
ls -la /cores/core*
-r--------   1 build  admin  1605496832 Jun 24 09:53 core.83754
-r--------   1 build  admin  1615982592 Jun 24 09:53 core.83773
-r--------   1 build  admin  1605496832 Jun 24 09:53 core.83797
```

When I tested the core files with a "file" command I saw it is indeed unreadable:

```
file /cores/core*
/cores/core.83754: Mach-O 64-bit core x86_64
/cores/core.83773: Mach-O 64-bit core x86_64
/cores/core.83797: data
```

I assume that it is a MacOS bug that it sometimes fails to write the coredump properly.